# Express.js WebSocket messages rate limit

Tags: express, websocket

I am writing a game on Express.js. Accordingly, communication between the client and the server mainly takes place over WebSockets. And now I have taken up the issue of protection against deliberate attacks by hackers. I want to limit the number of sent messages so that it is impossible to send more than 5 messages in a row, between each of which the difference is less than 100 ms.

I wrote this limiter:

```
const checkDdos = (client, clientID, count, lastTime) => {
    if (Date.now() - lastTime < 100) {
        count += 1
        if (count === 5) {
            new S_LOGIN_FAILED(
                client,
                '',
                {
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Lost connection by many requests per time!',
                    isServerWorks: false
                }
            )
            client.close()
            logger.error(`LOST CONNECTION BY MANY REQUESTS BY TIME: ${clientID}`)
        }
        console.log(count)
    } else {
        count = 0
    }
    lastTime = Date.now()
    return {count, lastTime}
}
```

Everything is fine, it disconnects the user, but often not after 5 messages, but 10, 30, 50 out of 1000. Since I send messages in a loop from the client:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        let i = 0
        while (i < 1000){
            console.log('DDOS', i)
            new C_GET_MISSION_ROAD_MAP()
            i++
        }

    }, [])
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix this disconnect delay so that it disconnects the user immediately after 5 messages and prevents them from sending any more?